# Windows not detecting HDMI?

Tags: windows, hdmi

I recently got a old Dell flatpanel tv with low resolution (1360 x 768). I decided that I would take a old Dell computer (Dell Inspiron 580) I had laying around and hook it up to the TV, but there was a problem, Windows didn't detect the TV via HDMI. On Ubuntu it works just fine, I even tested it with several other computers.

How come Windows can't detect this 1360 x 768 monitor via HDMI?

Comment: `I decided that I would take a old Dell computer ` is it a notebook? If so please connect your hdmi and post your screen resolution settings : http://www.elmajdal.net/win7/changing_screen_resolution_in_windows_7.aspx

Comment: It's not a notebook